# how to implement a class method on a function or a function constructor method on a class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is this even possible? I am in a situation, where I don't know what to use or what is better to use. I want to have something like `StringHelpers` class which will contain the methods for strings. I'm using react js, in my project I have `class` which extends to `Component class` and I have also got stateless functions. Now how I can use the `StringHelpers` methods on both of them.

My `StringHelpers` currently, I have an idea what to make of it.

```
class StringHelpers {
  constructor(string) {
    this.string = string;
  }

  toUcfirst() {
    return "ucfirst executing";
  }
}

export default StringHelpers;
```

**will I be able to achieve:**

```
`props.myString.toUcFirst()`;
```

In both classes and stateless functions.. how do I achieve something like this.. or I could also settle for other effective methods.

Comment: Why not simply have `stringHelpers` exporting functions and use them as imported functions wherever you want,

Comment: It seems you want to extend the String prototype. This is not advisable. Instead keep those helper functions out of the String prototype and rework your code to aim for a use like `StringHelpers.toUcFirst(props.myString)`.

Comment: This is generally very discouraged from a long experience of people doing this in the early days of javascript (around 2000-2009) to avoid clashing with other people's code. There used to be a very popular library called prototype.js which modified Array, String and Object with additional methods. Later when they released new versions of the library it clashed with user's code. Later still ES5 decided add new methods with the same name but different API so they clashed with javascript itself. Don't do it unless you're implementing a polyfill for future ES standards (ES7 etc)

Comment: ... so yes, it is possible but no, I won't tell you how to do it - don't do it

Comment: @slebetman okay I won't use it .. but can you please demonstrate it how it could've been acheived? just for education..

Comment: @trincot how can I use a class `StringHelpers` like that? I should export it as a function object right?

Comment: `StringHelpers` would be an object with function members. You *could* make it a class with `static` methods, but that is overkill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply export functions from `stringHelpers` instead of making it a class and than import those function wherever you need

```
//stringHelpers.js

export function capitalizeFirstChar(str){
   return str && str.replace(/^[a-z]/, (match)=> match.toUpperCase()) || ''
}

// test.js

import {capitalizeFirstChar} from './stringHelpers.js'
console.log(capitalizeFirstChar('hello world'))
```

Comment: Okay it looks fine as well.. can you explain your capitalize first char as well? ... I was thinking of use something like that.. Thanks

Comment: @ReyYoung this is just simple regex which matches first char of string and changes it to upperCase, you can add any number of function in `stringHelpers` and export them and use wherever is needed

Comment: on the replace() second argument... match parameter is the first matched letter?....

Comment: @ReyYoung yes, [Replace MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Parameters)

Comment: thanks.. but help me a little with the regex can you ?? `/` is the start and end of regez.. but what does those mean `^[a-z]/i` not characters a to z right?

Comment: @ReyYoung `^` means start of string, `[a-z]` means any character from a to z, `i` after `/` is flag for case insensitivity which is actually not needed here, [Regex graphical explanantion](https://jex.im/regulex/#!cmd=export&flags=&re=%5E%5Ba-z%5D)

Comment: okay.... hmm makes so much sense now... if the start of the string is lowercase letter then carry out the match function .. damn .... i thought `^` is not ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196071/discussion-between-code-maniac-and-rey-young).

Comment: There's a minor syntax error. Your argument is called `str` but internally you use `s`